# Prolog - How can I compare the results that came from two or more different predicates?

Tags: prolog

For example,

The first one is something like:

```
sum(X,Y,Result):- Result is X + Y.
```

The second one is:

```
times(X,Y,R):- R is X * Y.
```

Can I even define them like this?
Also what should I do if I want to write a thing that compare the value of two results? When I try to do something like `sum(X,Y,R1) > times(X,Y,R2)`, it doesn't allow me. I want to write a program that's true if `R1 > R2`. In this case, I want to get the sum of `X` and `Y` and the multiplication of `X` and `Y`, and find out which value is larger. How could I do that?

Comment: What do you mean with *compare them*? Prolog works with unification, so after a call `sum(1,4,X)`, `X` is unified with `5`. You can use `X` for whatever you want, inject it into another predicate, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be under the impression that a *predicate* returns something. A predicate however can only be `true` (the condition is satisfied, or variable can be unfied such that the predicate us satisfied), or `false` (the predicate is not satisfied, and unification can not satisfy it). A predicate can also error in case you call it the wrong way. But that is basically it: `true`, `false` (and error).

So it does not make sense to write something as `sum(X,Y,R1) > times(X,Y,R2)`, since nor `sum/3` nor `times/3` return something.

The idea of Prolog is to *unify* variables. If you write `sum(1,4,X)` then after the predicate call, `X` will be unified with `5`. So what you can do is write:

```
sum(X,Y,R1), times(X,Y,R2), R1 > R2.
```

This will however only work if `X` and `Y` are instantiated in the first place, since `is/2` requires the expression on the right side to be (fully) grounded.